# How to change the viewcontroller's background color from gray color to setting's color?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to change the viewcontroller's color.

Someone let me know like following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

}
```

Here is AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This is ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

But, result is that viewcontroller is black screen.

How to change to settings backgroundcolor?

[image]   [image]

Comment: What about other code? Are you sure that correct xib file is used?

Comment: Yeah, the snippet you posted should work. There has to be something else going on. iirc some templates have an empty loadView stub in them that has to be deleted for the view controller to appear? don't know if that's the issue but maybe worth checking?

Comment: I didn't use xib file. I make the viewcontroller just using init method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

Comment: Um.. I have tested above, but doesn't work. Also appear black screen.